# Detect Version of Excel in Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, excel-automation

I am currently using the following code to check to see if the Excel Automation libraries exist on the user's computer:

```
  CoInitialize(nil);
  ExcelExists := true;
  try
    TestExcel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  except
    ExcelExists := false;
  end;
  if ExcelExists then begin
    TestExcel.Workbooks.Close;
    TestExcel.Quit;
    TestExcel := Unassigned;
  end;
```

This has been working fine until one user only had Excel 2003. The above code said he had Excel, however my Excel automation does not work for him, and I suspect it won't work for versions prior to Excel 2003 either.

How can I check that the version of Excel that is installed is 2007 or later?

---

Based on David's answer, I ended up putting this after the if ExcelExists statement and it seems to do the job:

```
S := TestExcel.Application.Version;
if (copy(S, 3, 1) <> '.') or (S < '12') then
  ExcelExists := false;
```

Version 12 was Office 2007.

Comment: Using the Version property is fine and yes, version 12 is Excel 2007. Several automation related things changed in v12, mostly with internationalization, languages and so on. But I am wondering why wouldn't Excel 2003 work. We used automation with Excel since 1995 and all the basic things (like closing workbooks and quitting, like your eexample does) work the same.

Comment: Another alternative: 
`var LClassID: Winapi.ActiveX.TCLSID;
if (not (CLSIDFromProgID(PWideChar('Excel.Application'), LClassID) = S_OK)) then
    raise Exception.Create('Excel not installed!');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193301.aspx) property of the Excel `Application` object. Compare this against the minimum value that your code supports.